# How to HighLight a word in TextArea in Circular manner

Tags: java, swing, search, jtextarea

I wrote a code for Find a particular word in TextArea and HighLight it.But,It searches and highlights the word from the caret position to end of the TextArea.But,I want to search the word from caret position to end of the TextArea then from starting of the Textarea to end then start to end(Circular manner).I pasted here my Search method.Please Check it.Thank You.

My Search Word Method:

```
public void highLight(JTextArea component,String patteren){
    try {
        Document doc=component.getDocument();
        String text=component.getText(0,doc.getLength());
        int pos=component.getCaretPosition();
        int index=text.toLowerCase().indexOf(patteren.toLowerCase(),pos);
        if (index>=0) {
            component.setSelectionStart(index);
            component.setSelectionEnd(index+patteren.length());
            component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int index=text.toLowerCase().indexOf(patteren.toLowerCase(),pos);
    if (index>=0) {
        component.setSelectionStart(index);
        component.setSelectionEnd(index+patteren.length());
        component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
    }
    else {
        index=text.substring(0,pos).toLowerCase().indexOf(patteren.toLowerCase());
        if (index>=0) {
            component.setSelectionStart(index);
            component.setSelectionEnd(index+patteren.length());
            component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

If nothing is found use previous part of the text